# How can I share similar properties between two entities in Symfony using Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two doctrine entities that are very similar, but not the same.

I was thinking about creating an Interface or using abstract methods to share duplicate code between them, but unsure if this is best practice in regards to this.

I have two separate entities with many setters and getters that are very similar.

Which is the best approach in this case to share code between entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use `Embeddables`:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html

---

From the doctrine example, we have a `User` and `Address`.

The `Address` is also `embedded` for the `Company` entity.

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // Here we embed our Address entity

    /** @Embedded(class = "Address") */
    private $address;
}

/** @Entity */
class Company
{
    /** @Embedded(class = "Address") */
    private $address;
}

/** @Embeddable */
class Address
{
    // Our `shared` entity

    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    private $street;

    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    private $postalCode;

    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    private $city;

    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    private $country;
}
```

Read the docs for more info:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to think to [mapped superclasses](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) if your entities belong to the same domain.
If not [PHP Traits](http://php.net/traits) could also be a good choice